# jQuery - change for only clicked element, not all with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I would like to do is change an object's attribute, but for only that one. So something like, `$('.up img').attr("src","img/up.png")` for the one that has been clicked, not all the elements that have `.up img`.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.up img').click( function(){
        var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');
        $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
            console.log(o);
            if(o == 1){
                $('.up img').attr("src","img/up.png");
            }else if(o == 2){
                $('.up img').attr("src","img/up-g.png");
                $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw.png");
            }else if(o == 3){
                $('.up img').attr("src","img/up.png");
            }
        }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead to target only the particular element of that class which was clicked on, instead of using the class selector.

```
$('.up img').click( function(){
        var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');
        $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
            console.log(o);
            if(o == 1){
                $(this).attr("src","img/up.png");
            }else if(o == 2){
                $(this).attr("src","img/up-g.png");
                $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw.png");
            }else if(o == 3){
                $(this).attr("src","img/up.png");
            }
        }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could change your code to target the specific element.

```
$('.up img').click( function(){
    var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');

    // get the specific element that you have clicked.
    // i use the $ before the name to easily identify jquery elements.
    var $elm = $(this);

    $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
        console.log(o);
        if(o == 1){
            // targeting the specific element
            $elm.attr("src","img/up.png");
        }else if(o == 2){
            // targeting the specific element
            $elm.attr("src","img/up-g.png");
            $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw.png"); // not sure if you want to target individual element here?
        }else if(o == 3){
            // targeting the specific element
            $elm.attr("src","img/up.png");
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

If you are going to target the `$('.down img')` which is specific to the element that is clicked on, then you can use the `$elm` element to then traverse the DOM nodes.

Comment: ElSinus, please don't try to make huge edits to peoples answers like that

Comment: He tried to remove your last few sentences, and changed var $elm to var elm (no idea why)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('.up img').click( function(){
        var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');
        var clicked = $(this);
        $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
            console.log(o);
            if(o == 1){
                $(clicked).attr("src","img/up.png");
            }else if(o == 2){
                $(clicked).attr("src","img/up-g.png");
                $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw.png");
            }else if(o == 3){
                $(clicked).attr("src","img/up.png");
            }
        }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.up img').click( function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var postDataUp = $this.attr('mod');
    $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
        console.log(o);
        if(o == 1){
           $this.attr("src","img/up.png");
        }else if(o == 2){
            $this.attr("src","img/up-g.png");
            $this.attr("src","img/dw.png");
        }else if(o == 3){
            $this.attr("src","img/up.png");
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```