# hover image using jQuery's toggle() doesn't work in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, jsfiddle

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6DP9/2/) for the below.

The reason for creating this jsfiddle is that `animate()` doesn't work inside the `fadeOut()` function, but works outside :

```
$(".fader").click(function (e) {
    var self = this;
     $('.fader').not(self).fadeOut(function () {
        $(self).animate({top: "220",left: "200"}); // doesn't work
        LoadContent(fader.attr('id')); // works 
     });

     $(this).animate({top: "220", left: "200"}); // works
});
```

EDIT: ok I see the reason now that animate() didn't run - I was calling the wrong element (`this` instead of `self` which jsfiddle corrected). but still I don't know why toggle() doesn't work in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsFiddle` is wrong. First of all You don't use any jQuery library, as the file you are refering to in first line does not exist. Second is that You are trying to apply click event to object with class `.fader` but not the one that was clicked. And there is no other object with that class. Use `parents()` instead. And function (as u call) "inside" fadeOut is triggered at the end of fadeOut so your code is kind of senseless.

If you want to animate and fadeout at same time, use only animate:

```
$('.fader').animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-1000px", left: "-1000px" }, 'slow');
```

Comment: so how do I apply click event to object that was clicked instead of all class? I'm using `$(this)` because I thought that it refers to one object only (as according to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166561/jquery-change-for-only-clicked-element-not-all-with-the-same-class)), am I wrong?
`animate` is meant to be triggered at the end of `fadeOut` - that's ok for me, so nvm about that.

Comment: $(this) is fine, but Your selector $('.fader').not(this) means -> all objects that have fader class but not the one. This doesn't have sense when assigning click event, because only after click it knows what is `this`. Just assign click event to `.fader` and then in click function use `$(this)` or `this`. If You want to fadeout only things inside `this` use `$(this).children()`;