# change the style of only the element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I have been making this form that has different inputs but they all have the same class:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="field" /> 
<input type="text" name="email" calss="field" />
```

what i want to do is when ever the input filed is clicked i want to change the border color with JQuery(only the element that is clicked not all at the same time)

any one got an idea?

Comment: Make sure you spell "field" correctly for each of the classes

Comment: It is because you did absolutely zero research

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - change for only clicked element, not all with the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166561/jquery-change-for-only-clicked-element-not-all-with-the-same-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="field" /> 
<input type="text" name="email" calss="field" />  




$('.field').click(function(){
     $(this).css('attributeName','value'); //here $(this) represents current element.
});
```

Comment: This will style every textbox you clicked in. Not only the active one.

Comment: and if someone moves to next textbox using tab it will not be styled.

Answer (score 2):

Bind a click event to all inputs, then use $(this) to target the one that was actually clicked .

```
$('.field').on('click', function() {
     $('.field').removeClass('clicked'); // Remove previous
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.addClass('clicked'); // If you want to add the CSS with a class, which i recommend.
     $this.css('border', '[css-border-values]'); // Inline CSS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="field" /> 
<input type="text" name="email" calss="field" /> 

$('input[type=text]').focus(function(){
     $('input[type=text]').css({'border':''});
     $(this).css({'border':'solid 2px #ccc'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jCpfH/